# optmize delete based on "count" of elements in table with foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I has two tables, "tracks" (header of track and track_points - points in track).
Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tracks(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
  start_time TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE track_points (
  id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  data   BLOB,
  track_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(track_id) REFERENCES tracks(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX track_id_idx ON track_points (track_id);
CREATE INDEX start_time_idx ON tracks (start_time);
```

And I want delete all "tracks" that has 0 or 1 point.
Note if 0 points in tracks, then it has no rows in "track_points".

I write such query:

```sql
DELETE FROM tracks WHERE tracks.id IN
   (SELECT track_id FROM 
           (SELECT tracks.id as track_id, COUNT(track_points.id) as track_len FROM tracks
                   LEFT JOIN track_points ON tracks.id=track_points.track_id GROUP BY tracks.id)
           WHERE track_len<=1)
```

it seems to work, but I wonder is it possible to optmize such query?
I mean time of work (now 10 seconds on big table on my machine).
Or may be simplification of this SQL code is possible (with preservance of work time of course)?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by removing 1 level of your subqueries, because you can achieve the same with a `HAVING` clause instead of an outer `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE FROM tracks 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT t.id
  FROM tracks t LEFT JOIN track_points p
  ON t.id = p.track_id 
  GROUP BY t.id
  HAVING COUNT(p.id) <= 1
);
```

The above code may not make any difference, but it's simpler.

The same logic could also be applied by using `EXCEPT`:

```
DELETE FROM tracks 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM tracks
  EXCEPT
  SELECT track_id
  FROM track_points
  GROUP BY track_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

What you can try is a query that does not involve the join of the 2 tables.
Aggregate only in `track_points` and get the `track_id`s with 2 or more occurrences. Then delete all the rows from `tracks` with `id`s that are not included in the result of the previous query:

```
DELETE FROM tracks 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT track_id
  FROM track_points
  GROUP BY track_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: The second variant I used before, but it works 11 seconds instead of 8 seconds for variant in question. I suppose this is because of tracks with 0 or 1 points is ~10%, and the majority of has more the one point, so the internal query generate huge number of rows.

Comment: @user1244932 in that case `IN` performs better than `NOT IN`. Try another variation with `EXCEPT` in my edited answer.